# What are the weapons with improved damage when using the heavy barrel?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

In Rainbow Six Siege, the heavy barrel is can be misleading sometimes. On some weapons, it may reduce the damage at closer ranges or sometimes improve it.

What are the weapons where the damage improves from all ranges while using the attachment (making it a viable attachment)?

Comment: After a bit of looking it seems like information on heavy barrel (extended barrel) is really sparse. Not enough for a complete answer but you can see some damage charts here in [the patch notes](https://rainbow6.ubisoft.com/siege/en-ca/news/164-322394-16/12-patch-notes) and a [youtube video looking at its effectiveness here](https://youtu.be/b79vCwE_92k).